# Sharepoint hosted app showing access denied error

Tags: sharepoint-addin

I am a  beginner in sharepoint 2013 and started developing Sharepoint hosted Apps using client side objst model. I am  able to deploy sample Apps from provided in msdn site; ie.just for reading the current user's name.

But when we try to write our own logic for view / add/ edit an item from a custom list, we are getting the following error.

Sharepoint hosted Apps supports only clinet side scripting and we are using the foloowing code for testing

But unfortunately the deployment ends with an error  and we are not able to proceed further.

Comment: I have the same issue, even when adding the appropriate permission in the appmanifest.xml, still having "access denied"

Answer (score 2):

If you are manipulating the SharePoint List data like editing, deleting or adding.

For this operations you need to provide some permission to the `AppManifest.xml`.
e.g
If you are Manipulating SharePoint List Items you need to provide Permission to
list --> write.

Access denied error mostly arise because you not have given permission to the `AppManifest.xml`.

Comment: What else can we do to troubleshoot the problem if setting Full Control for Tenant in AppManifest doesn't help?